# I don't get why my .find function don't work

Tags: c++, find, getline

I have a problem with this code. My if statement for `userInput.find("=")` is always true :

```
std::string userInput;
while (1)
{
  std::cout << "> ";
  getline(std::cin, userInput);
  if (std::cin.eof())
  {
    std::cout << "Program Exit" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  if (userInput == "exit")
  {
    std::cout << "Program exit" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  if (userInput.find("="))
  {
    std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

output :

```
./main
> print a
yes
> exit
> Program Exit
```

But I don't see any "=" in my "print a" sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the reference for `std::string.find`.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Note it says it returns the position of the query, or if none, returns `string::npos`, which if you follow through will see `string::npos = -1 = SIZE_MAX`. (this is the only un-used number in the `size_t` number space, as a string might have indices all the way from 0 up to `SIZE_MAX-1`) Any non-zero integer coerces to true, so your statement will always be true.

Change to check if `find != string::npos`.

Comment: To be accurate `std::string::npos` is not equal to -1 as it is unsigned

Comment: My apologies, I skimmed the references extremely quickly in order to win the answer race. I shall correct the record.

Answer (score 3):

`userInput.find()` does not return a `bool`.  It will return [npos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if it does not find it, and your check will construct a boolean from npos, which will be TRUE.

Answer:  check for `npos` explicitly